# Combining assigning Object literal to new array and forEach over another array at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, push

Hello I have this code and It's **working**

```
  for (let i in list) {
    db.push({
      name: list[i],
      values: []
    });

    for (let j in data) {
      db[i].values.push({
        Date: data[j].Date,
        count: parseInt(data[j][list[i]])
      });
    };
    db[i].values.pop();
  };
```

Im trying to convert it to this

```
  list.forEach((el, i) => {
    db.push({
      name: list[i],
      values: Array.prototype.call(data.forEach((d, j) => {
        this.push({
          Date: data[j].Date,
          count: parseInt(data[j][list[i]])
        });
      }))
    })
  })
```

Comment: There is no `Array.prototype.call` method.

Comment: Please add the initial values of `db`, `list` and `data` to your code snippet. From the current post it's not even clear whether they are objects or arrays.

Comment: as I said the first part is working, Im trying to Improve my code , so Its clear they are Arrays

Comment: In that case, have a look at [why is using `for…in` on arrays such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could slice data to get only the items without the last and map the value.

```
let shortData = data.slice(0, -1),
    db = list.map(name => ({
        name,
        values: shortData.map(({ Date, [name]: count }) => ({
            Date,
            count: +count
        })
    });
```

Comment: you opened a new window for me